# How to compare System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.PropertyType with System.Type

Tags: .net, vb.net, types, properties, system.reflection

I need from a class all list properties. I try it with the following code:

```vb
Public Sub foo(Of T)(source AS T)
  source.GetType.GetProperties.ToList.
    ForEach(Sub(item)
      If (item.PropertyType Is GetType(IEnumerable(Of Object))) Then 'do something
      If (TypeOf item.PropertyType Is IEnumerable(Of Object)) Then 'do something

      If (item.PropertyType Is GetType(ICollection(Of Object))) Then 'do something
      If (TypeOf item.PropertyType Is ICollection(Of Object)) Then 'do something

      If (item.PropertyType Is GetType(IList(Of Object))) Then 'do something
      If (TypeOf item.PropertyType Is IList(Of Object)) Then 'do something

      If (TypeOf item.PropertyType Is List(Of Object)) Then 'do something
    )
End Sub
```

All if clauses are false. The `item.PropertyType` property contains System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyNamespace.MyClass].

The following sample is true

```vb
If (TypeOf New List(Of MyNamespace.MyClass) Is IEnumerable(Of Object)) Then 'do something
```

and this is also false

```vb
If (New List(Of MyNamespace.MyClass)().GetType Is GetType(IEnumerable(Of Object))) Then 'do something
```

What is the difference between the examples that the first and third doesn't work like wanted?

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)